Why doesn’t Lenovo ThinkPad battery seem to work?
Lenovo ThinkPad 5 Gen laptop. In the Vantage Settings I have  the battery care option turned on. However, the battery charges to 95% or sometimes 100%.
I did not find where the threshold is set in Vantage settings. So the default threshold is kept. I guess it is much lower than 95%. How can I make it limit the charge level?
So my question is not about extending the time on battery. Just the opposite. I want to limit its charge level when plugged in  on AC power.
As for the BIOS version, Vantage shows this:

BIOS version: LMCN18WW
Vantage program version: 10.2406.36

This can be found from the user icon at top right of the Vantage window; there: About item.

What version of the software do you have installed

@Ramhound thanks! :) I've edited the question to add  at the bottom this: I did not find where to see the version of the  Vantage  program.  As for the BIOS version, Vantage shows this:
Bios Version: LMCN18WW
If you mean Vantage  version, any idea of where to see it? I  guess Windows  software has nothing to do with this? Actually Windows-11 What else software  do you mean?  I have MS  Office  and some other programs installed.

So are you trying to lower the charging threshold to something below 95%? It seems odd you say it sometimes charges past 95%

@Ramhound Yes, I would like to lower the threshold to something like 40%, which seems to be the typical value. I expected that just enabling the battery care option  in Vantage would do that. I think there is a setting for specifying this threshold hidden somewhere in Vantage, but I cannot find it. Any idea?

Apps and Programs (the new add/remove programs) should show software versions. Also, if there's an About or Help menu in the application, that will likely show software version. Regardless, you should go to the Lenovo support site and download and install the latest version offered there, as well as any other firmware and driver updates, and then you'll know which version you're running, AND you'll be running the latest version which may include bug fixes you need.

@Ramhound The version of the Lenovo Vantage program itself  is: 10.2406.36
Was your question about this? Or about the operating system, any other software installed, or  the BIOS? Should I download another version of the program?
